# Swift: UIButton on UILabel

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton, uilabel

In some circumstance, I have to make a UILabel clickable.
I tried many answers from stackOverflow to make the UIlabelClickable, but they were not working.

So eventually, I decided to position UIButton on the UILabel, and make the button transparent.

However, although the button correctly position on top of the Label, clicking the button does not interact. Any idea?

Thanks

Edit: In addition, there are two views, say view1 and view2. Due to structure of my app, I placed the UIButton and UILabel on view 2, and then placed view 2 on view1.
So:

```
view2.addSubview(button)
view1.addSubview(view2)
```

Comment: Why don't you remove the UILabel entirely and just use the UIButton? A UIButton is basically a clickable UILabel.

Comment: The reason is because there are multiple functions run for the UILabel, and so I cannot change to UIButton.

Comment: Why can't you just run those functions on a UIButton instead?

Comment: Initially, my app did not require tapping action, but now it needs. I mean I can switch the functions to get UIButton instead of UILabel, but since there are many functions, I just did not want to modify them all. But if that is the only way, I will do that thanks

Comment: FancyLabel is exactly what you need http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/

Comment: Why don't you just toggle the UIButton's userInteractionEnabled? That way it'd be like it's both a button and a label?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the UILabel's userInteractionEnabled to true, as UILabel inherits that property from its UIView super-class.

I forgot to mention, you would have to use a tap gesture recogniser with the label, as UILabel does not inherit from UIControl the way it did in the beginning.

Having said that, you could simply add a tap gesture recogniser to your UILabel.

Comment: Apparently, my button was out of superview, and that was why it was not working. Sorry for asking dumb question and thank you for all the helps

Answer (score 0):

A view with an opacity of zero is not tappable. Give the button a very small opacity, but not quite zero. It won't be visible, but it will now be tappable.

Alternatively, use a normal button with no title and a background color of whose alpha is close to zero but not quite zero. Again, this won't be visible, but it will be tappable.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a UILabel to be clickable then you need to remove the label and use UIButton and change the name of the button to what ever your label says. This will appear like a label but will be clickable.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Actually a `UIButton` has a `titleLabel` on it. So it is fine to use a `UIButton` when you want a clickable `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

First I will answer fir your question. There are 2 possibilities

1) The UILabel might be on top of UIButton, So you need to take UIButton on UILabel.

2) You might have made UIButton colour to clear colour which make Alpha to 0.0f. This make button un-clickable. So you need to change its colour settings. And make Alpha to 1.0

The **Best way** to use UIButton only and not to use UIButton and UILabel. OR only UILabel with userInteractionEnabled property.